# deprecated mouse wheel event with csfml

Tags: c, gcc, sfml

Basically I have been programming in csfml and when I try to compile my code it will give me two warnings the first one would be: 'sfMouseWheelEvent' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]and the second warning is: deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations].

typedef struct CSFML_DEPRECATED I've been trying to execute the programm but it gives me a window which doesn't show up and stops reacting imediatly.

Comment: This is not an uncommon problem.  There are [some suggestions in this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/367264/prevent-deprecated-code-from-compiling-after-reaching-a-deadline). (not all good, but some worth considering it this really bothers you.)  I like the 4th answer best.  Deprecation is not really so bad a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps: https://www.sfml-dev.org/changelog.php#sfml-2.3

> Deprecated API
>
> sf::Event::MouseWheelEvent: This event is deprecated and potentially inaccurate. Use MouseWheelScrollEvent instead.

Comment: even if i never used the function inside the code ?

Comment: Ah, OK, but you didn't say that :-)